# Sending POST to URL

Tags: php, http, url, post, send

I want to redirect a PHP page to another one sending to it data by *HTTP POST* method.

I can't use cURL because I need relative *URLs* (the function is going to be called from different locations), so I found this function online:

```
function head($url)
{
    $string = http_build_query($GLOBALS['new']);//$GLOBALS['new'] is an array containing some variables and I already tested it using var_dump()

    $options = array('method'=>'POST', 'header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content'=>$string);
    file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array('http'=>$options)));

    echo error_get_last()['message'];//temporary to see the error message

    header("Location: $url");
}
```

I would invoke it by typing `head(".?result=success)` or something like that...

---

The problem is that I get this error message

`file_get_contents(.?result=success): failed to open stream: No error`

and the destination page does not receive anything.

---

Whatever it means, I can't find any way to fix it, and even removing the *HTTP GET* method or putting absolute paths instead (even if it is not my purpuse) nothing changes.

**Can you find me a way to make it work?**

**Or, if not possible, could you suggest me another method to send *HTTP POST* using relative *URLs*?**

Comment: `head(".?result=success)`, did you mean `header("Location:?result=success")`?
No dot should be needed

Comment: @dalelandry the output is the same (*initial single dot* at the beginning is optional for relative paths)

Comment: Did you include the page you are sending to header request to?
For example if I am sending the header redirect from a index page and checking to see if result is set on say contact page my header redirect would look like `header("Location: http://<--yoursite-->/contact.php?result=success")`

Comment: The function file_get_contents cannot work with a relative URL, it must be a full URL. But you can build the full URL using super global var $_SERVER.

Comment: @dalelandry I can't understand the difference between this and my code...

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP I get confused with all those variables, some of which even contain the same value... And the reference does not help a lot because I don't catch which one would be the best one for a cross-site purpuse

Comment: Answer from @dale-landry shows you a way to build the entire URL.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP so why doesn't [this](https://pastebin.com/fc75KXvg) work?

Comment: The function head($url) doesn't work as you want, it redirects without sending post data. Look here for header() use to send post data: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-do-redirect-in-php-with-post-and-not-get/4968

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP so should I use these commands `header("POST $path HTTP/1.1\\r\
" );`, `header("Host: $host\\r\
" );`, `header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\\r\
" );`, `header("Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\\r\
" );`, `header("Connection: close\\r\
\\r\
" );`, `header($data);` to submit a POST?

Comment: @Fox Try yourself and debug if it's necessary.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP it starts downloading a file which contains this message `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in <b>` *my file path* `\login.inc.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
`

Comment: @Fox I can't help you to debug everything, I'm sorry. You are on the way.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP ` Try yourself and debug if it's necessary` (your words)

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example of code I use in my sites user class for login

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];            // Get the server
$url .= rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\'); // Get the current directory
$url .= 'index.php?error';            // <-- Your relative path
header('Location: ' . $url, true, 302);
exit;
```

Then on my index.php page I have an if statement that evaluates

`if(isset($_GET[error])){ //set error message and handle error }`

Comment: what does *302* mean?

Comment: `file_get_contents` still doesn't send *HTTP POST* data

Comment: 302 is a response status code... 

Mozilla MDN: An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL in the header field Location. This is an invitation to the user agent (e.g. a web browser) to make a second, otherwise identical, request to the new URL specified in the location field. The end result is a redirection to the new URL.

Comment: and what about sending POST to that URL?

Comment: How is your POST generated? 
Is this a POST coming from a form or from another source?
Are you looking to dynamically create a header() redirect and then apply a POST variable to that URL?

Comment: It is a simple array (let's call it `$data`) that I want to send from `page1.php` to `page2.php` while redirecting, so that `page2.php` could find `$data` into `$_POST`.